# Can a non-UI component receive Notifications in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a data helper class which connects to a database and keeps a local cache up to date. This is not a `Widget`, so it has no UI.

When the user takes an action like clicking a button, an MQTT call is made and an asynchronous response is received. This response is then propagated to various Widgets through a `Riverpod Notifier`.

I want to receive this notification in my data helper class also, so that I can update the state in the database. But my helper class does not have a `build()` method, nor a `BuildContext`. Can I somehow implement an `Observer` in this class? I am willing to use `ChangeNotifier` or `ValueNotifier`, or any plugin.